# Certificate isn't properly loading in jax-ws webservices deployed on weblogic server

Tags: glassfish, weblogic, jax-ws

I have some simple web service application in glassfish server where request need certificate to authorization. There are couple of certificate. Which I want to use depend on id: This works on glassfish:

```
MyCustomPortType service;
...
// set certifikate
setSSLSocketFactory(id, (BindingProvider) service);
// send request
final MyCustomType response = service.process(params);
```

now I need to deploy this application on weblogic and here is the problem. Now just pass request with first id and other request return error because they have bad certificate. I think in weblogic there is some cache which miss in glassfish and request still contains same certificate even SSLSocketFactory is different

UPDATE:

I read this article: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/secmanage/ssl.html#wp1194460 but I have no idea how to implement this in my app

UPDATE2:

```
  protected void setSSLSocketFactory(final String agenda, final BindingProvider service) {
    service.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY,
        MutualSSLContext.getFactory(configuration, agenda));
  }

  public static final SSLSocketFactory getFactory(final RobaktConfiguration cfg, final String agenda) {

if (cfg == null || agenda == null) {
  return null;
}

  try {
    final File keyStore = cfg.getKeystorePath(agenda);
    final KeyManager[] keyManagers;
    if (keyStore != null) {
      keyManagers = new KeyManager[] {new MutualKeyManager(cfg, agenda)};
    } else {
      keyManagers = null;
    }
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sslContext.init(keyManagers, new TrustManager[] {new MutualTrustManager()}, null);
    final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    return sslSocketFactory;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new MutualSSLException(e.getMessage(), e);
  }
```

}

Class `MutualKeyManager` implement interface `X509ExtendedKeyManager`. I can't add it here

Comment: Couple of questions to give a correct answer: 1. Cant you let WLS decide which cert to use based on the servers request? 2. How is `setSSLSocketFactory` implemented? Could you post some code?

Comment: nope, question updated

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Ok. I think I see the problem...</strike> What version of WLS are you trying? WLS < 12.1.1 uses a Certicom based SSL-implementation. Have you tried setting `Use JSSE` in the Weblogic console (it's somewhere in Security -> Advanced - I dont have an older version of WLS around ATM)?

Since you already tried switching to JSSE - one last option I can think of is using `weblogic.security.SSL.SSLContext`. You would basically do the same thing you are doing now:

```
SSLContext context = weblogic.security.SSL.SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
Certificate[] certs = ...; // load the certificates from your prop-files keystore
PrivateKey privKey = ...; // load the private key from your keystore
context.loadLocalIdentity(certs, key);

service.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, context.getSocketFactory());
```

Comment: yes I try to use JSSE in weblogic admin console but with no success

Comment: hm  and which maven dependency contains this class ?

Comment: `weblogic.jar` Since weblogic is a commercial product you wont find the libs in repo1. :-) You will need to install the `weblogic.jar` to your local repo.